# Combine many array values to related array vlaue with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have been working with Angularjs for a few weeks now and am starting to LOVE it, but I have one last problem to solve that has alluded me...

Basically I have two json files with related values.. meaning there is one common key in each json file that I want to use to do what in SQL would be a join of sorts.. This is a one to many relationship.  So one value related to multiple values.  I'm close but I just can't seem to figure out how to say "for this array value, grab all of these related values from this other file then display them as one result".

I've also included Underscorejs and injected it into my controller as a possible way to solve this as well..

I'm not familiar enough yet to figure this out but here is my code so far:

Contents of the ab_activities.json (the file with the "many"):

```
[
  {
    "unique_id":"001",
    "state":"NY",
    "state_id":"1.S2.3a"
  },
  {
    "unique_id":"001",
    "state":"NY",
    "state_id":"1.S3.2d"
  },
  {
    "unique_id":"001",
    "state":"FL",
    "state_id":"SC.4.N.1.D"
  }
]
```

Contents of the ee_activities.json file (the "one" related value):

```
[
  {
    "unique_id":"001",
    "title":"Some Title",
    "url_title":"some-title"
  }
]
```

Angular code:

```
var underscore = angular.module('underscore', []);

underscore.factory('_', function() {
    return window._;
});

var abApp = angular.module('abApp', ['underscore']);

abApp.factory('abData', function($http, $q) {
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    var data = [];
    var abData = {};

    abData.async = function() {
        $http.get('/data/ab_activities.json')
            .success(function(ab) {
                data = ab;
                deffered.resolve();
            });
        $http.get('/data/ee_activities.json')
            .success(function(ee) {
                data = ee;
                //deffered.resolve();
            });
        return deffered.promise;
    };
    abData.data = function() {
        return data;
    };

    return abData;
});

abApp.controller("abEE", function(abData, $scope) {
    var abApp = this;
    abData.async().then(function(d) {
    abApp.subjects = abData.data();
    });
})
```

And HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="abEE as ee">
    <p ng-repeat="subject in ee.subjects">
    <strong><a href="/activities/{{subject.url_title}}">{{subject.title}}</a></strong>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="???">{{subject.state}}, {{subject.state_id}}</li>
  </ul>
 </p>
</div>
```

And finally - What I'm hoping to achieve:

**Title: Some Title**

- NY, 1.S2.3a
- NY, 1.S3.2d
- FL, SC.4.N.1.D

The {{subject.state}} / {{subject.state_id}} are the many related values.. and I'm trying to relate the results by the "unique_id".

Right now the interesting thing that is happening is that there is one value from the ab_activities.json file that is being displayed multiple times because deffered.resolve(); is set on the ee_activities.json values and that is the one that has the "many to one" values.

I'm thinking that I can use a "forEach()" function then somehow pass the value that I want to relate back, then use underscore's ._where() function to get the related values??  Just not sure yet, hopefully someone will have some Angular code brilliance that can help out :-)

Comment: Can you post your json files and the desired structure after the "join"?

Comment: @AnthonyChu - added the Json stuff and simplified the html a bit..

Comment: ee.subjects ???????  does it even there in controller ??? If yes, i'm not able to see it. after observing your code, I've found that your code won't work properly. Please check browser's console to check possible error. If there is no problem then tell me what you are getting in ee.subjects?????

Comment: @micronyks - Sorry, I'm still really new to Angular :-/..  I think "ee" is an alias for the abEE controller?  ng-controller="abEE as ee"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are making it very complex through your existing code. its very simple to implement. I'm providing you fiddle. go through it carefully.

here is fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/micronyks/9DcXA/2/)

First of all, in this fiddle i'm using your json objects directly without making any server trip. so you have to manage, when you are modifying your code, on your own.

This will help you a lot to learn new thing...(its very easy)

I'm showing you dynamic way to bind data conditionally as per your requirement.

now if you have more data, angular will manage on its own...

html page.

```
<html ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">

        <div ng-repeat="title in titles">
            <div>{{title.title}}</div>
                <div ng-repeat="state in states|filter:{unique_id:title.unique_id}">
                    <div >{{state.state}}{{state.state_id}}</div>
                </div>
        </div>
    <div>
</html>
```

your controller .js file

```
function ctrl($scope) {

        $scope.states = [
  {
    "unique_id":"001",
    "state":"NY",
    "state_id":"1.S2.3a"
  },
  {
    "unique_id":"001",
    "state":"NY",
    "state_id":"1.S3.2d"
  },
  {
    "unique_id":"001",
    "state":"FL",
    "state_id":"SC.4.N.1.D"
  }
];

        $scope.titles = [
  {
    "unique_id":"001",
    "title":"Some Title",
    "url_title":"some-title"
  }
];

    }
```

EDITED:

Updated fiddle according to your existing html page in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/micronyks/9DcXA/3/)

Comment: Beautiful @micronyks!  Thank you, I'm starting to "get it" :-)